# Bind value from one array of objects based on id from different one using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a list of options and then I call an API which validates those options. I plan to display whether an option is valid or not.
I start with this array

```
$scope.preValidationArray = [
  { id: 1, description: 'Item 1' },
  { id: 2, description: 'Item 2' },
  { id: 3, description: 'Item 3' },
];
```

and get the following response

```
$scope.validations = [
  { id: 1, valid: true },
  { id: 2, valid: false },
  { id: 3, valid: false },
];
```

how can I use ng-repeat to match the right id and NOT rebuild the array again. I would rather just update the valid property on the original array whenever I get a new set of validations. I'm thinking of something like `<div ng-bind="validations.valid on option.id">`

```
<ul id="options">
   <li ng-repeat="option in preValidationArray track by option.id"
       ng-class="{'invalid': !option.valid}">
      <div ng-bind="option.description"></div>
      //////////////// Here I want to do something like
      Valid: <div ng-bind="validations.valid on option.id">
   </li>
</ul>
```

I am going to have a Revalidate button which is going to return the set of validations again so ideally I don't want to rebuild this array over and over again.

Bare in mind I have to trigger a class on `<li>` element using ng-class if it's invalid.

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution would be using another `ng-repeat` for the validations:

```
<ul id="options">
    <li ng-repeat="option in preValidationArray track by option.id">
        <div ng-bind="option.description"></div>

        Valid: <div ng-repeat="validation in validations | filter:{id:option.id} track by validation.id">{{validation.valid}}</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Check demo: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pz4a9d06/8/)

Comment: Haven't mentioned that in the description but I need to apply a class using ng-class based on whether option's valid so having another ng-repeat underneath wouldn't apply a class to my <li> element

Answer (score 0):

Are your preValidationArray and validations arrays 1:1? Meaning, if pre-validation has 15 elements, does validations as well (and does validations[0] correspond to preValidationArray[0] and so on)? If so you *could* track on the index and be safe in this instance. With that caveat in mind, you could try something like this:

```
<ul id="options">
    <ng-repeat="option in preValidationArray track by $index">
        <ng-bind="option.description"></div>
        Valid: <div ng-bind="validations[$index].valid">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: They can appear in different order each time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a function:

```
$scope.validById = function(id) {
    return $scope.validations.find(_ => _.id == id).valid;
};
```

And use it:

```
<ul id="options">
   <li ng-repeat="option in preValidationArray track by option.id"
       ng-class="{'invalid': !validById(option.id)}">
      <div ng-bind="option.description"></div>
      //////////////// Here I want to do something like
      ̶V̶a̶l̶i̶d̶:̶ ̶<̶d̶i̶v̶ ̶n̶g̶-̶b̶i̶n̶d̶=̶"̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶a̶t̶i̶o̶n̶s̶.̶v̶a̶l̶i̶d̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶i̶d̶"̶>̶
      Valid: <div ng-bind="validById(option.id)"></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```